# What are the disadvantages (if any) of using a supercritical airfoil?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, airfoil

The title sums up my question pretty well.

I've searched all over this site, having read many of the questions and answers to various supercritical wing topics, but I haven't found any mention of disadvantages to using them.

Are there any?

Comment: My guess: drag or lift/drag ratio at low to medium sub sonic speed is sub optimal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A supercritical airfoil has these characteristics:

- Large leading edge radius
- Comparably flat upper surface
- Rounded lower surface with a maximum thickness location at around 50%
- Flat or even negative camber in the forward section
- High positive camber in the rear section (rear loading)

The large leading edge radius allows it to create more lift than comparable airfoils at high angle of attack. After [R. Whitcomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_T._Whitcomb) re-invented [supercritical airfoils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercritical_airfoil) (they had first be developed by K. A. Kawalki in Germany in 1940, and British airfoil research resulted in similar shapes, first used in the [VC-10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vickers_VC10)), he transferred some of their characteristics to a GA airfoil, the [GA(W)-1](http://airfoiltools.com/airfoil/details?airfoil=ls417-il).

From the [Wikipedia article on Whitcomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_T._Whitcomb):

> The unusual airfoil unexpectedly aided general aviation as well; its
>   rather blunt leading edge allowed it to generate high lift
>   coefficients before stalling, and Whitcomb published a low-speed
>   airfoil which he called GA(W)-1; it is now routinely used in light
>   aircraft and gliders.

As usual, Wikipedia is mostly correct, but the use of the GA(W)-1 on gliders is everything but routine. This gives an indication of their drawbacks:

1. The low forward camber limits the range of the laminar bucket to lower lift coefficients. A [good glider airfoil](http://airfoiltools.com/airfoil/details?airfoil=fx62k131-il) tries to maintain the laminar bucket almost up to stall.
2. A positive camber throughout will produce higher maximum lift coefficients than what a supercritical airfoil is capable of. That is why the GA(W)-1 uses only the blunt nose and the rear loading, but not the camber distribution of supercritical airfoils.
3. The high rear loading gives them a large, negative pitch coefficient which translates into a larger travel of the center of pressure over angle of attack, requiring a larger horizontal tail. In airliners this does not matter because their large flaps dictate the size of the tail.

Comment: Funny you (er, Wikipedia) should mention using supercritical wings on gliders... I gleaned (from the Q&A here on Aviation SE) that supercritical airfoils benefit aircraft whose flight regimes are in the high subsonic range.  I can't think of any *gliders* going that fast!

Comment: @pr1268  A few gliders are very fast, even supersonic. For example, the 'Shuttle'...

Comment: @pr1268: For one, the GA(W)-1 is not a supercritical airfoil anymore. Also, it is **not** routinely used on gliders, regardless of what Wikipedia claims.

Comment: @xxavier: Okay, but can the Space Shuttle soar on thermals for long periods of time? ;-)

Comment: @pr1268  No, but we were talking about *gliders*, not sailplanes...